# scaling issue on click event

Tags: unity-game-engine, scale

I am developing a 2D game in Unity. I've created a character panel in that to let player select different character. In panel, there are thumbnails for different character. By tapping on a particular character thumbnail, the player can view that character. The original scale of thumbnail is 1, and when player taps on thumbnail, the scale get doubles. All is fine till this. but issue is that whenever player taps on thumbnail its scale gets double. But i want to limit it to once only. I've used flag to stop scaling, But still issue is there. After flag it stops scaling, but now player can click on multiple character simultaneously. I am copying snippet here.

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.UI;
 using System.Collections;

public class ViewCharacter : MonoBehaviour {

[SerializeField]
private GameObject TempCharacterHolder ,TempCharacter, TempCharacterText, TempCharacterPrice;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    for (int i = 0; i < ShoppingManager.instance.ShoppingList.Count; i++) {
        if (i == TheGameController.instance.GetSelectedCharacter ()) {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("CharacterScaled" + i, 1);
        } else {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("CharacterScaled" + i, 0);
        }
    }
}

public void ViewCharacterFunc()
{
    int ClickedCharacter = int.Parse (TempCharacterText.GetComponent<Text> ().text);

    foreach (var characters in ShoppingManager.instance.ShoppingList) {
        if (string.Equals (characters.CharacterName, TempCharacterText.GetComponent<Text> ().text)) {
            if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("CharacterScaled"+characters.CharacterName)==0) {
                ShoppingManager.instance.IncreaseScale (TempCharacter, TempCharacterHolder);

                for (int i = 0; i < ShoppingManager.instance.ShoppingList.Count; i++) {
                    if (i == ClickedCharacter) {
                        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("CharacterScaled" + i, 1);
                    } else {
                        PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("CharacterScaled" + i, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            Color clr = characters.Character_Holder.GetComponent<Image> ().color;
            clr.a = 1;
            characters.Character_Holder.GetComponent<Image> ().color = clr;

            Vector3 TempVector = characters.CharaacterObject.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().localScale;
            TempVector.x = 1f;
            TempVector.y = 1f;
            characters.CharaacterObject.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().localScale = TempVector;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you please give more exact details on the situation, and some examples of the code you are using and/or even screenshots of the issue?

Comment: You might want to look at this page on how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I think it's a shame to vote down questions just because the English is a bit rough, from a non-native speaker.  The question, while basic, is perfectlly sensible and clear.  I see **ten questions** in the Unity tag currently which are total trash, with no downvotes.

Comment: Shame on anyone who voted this question down.  I just clicked "edit" and repaired all the simple grammar problems, with 20 characters.  Don't vote questions down because someone is not a native English speaker.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, your characters scale numerous times when you click on them instead of scaling once.

If that's the case, I'd suggest controlling that with a bool:

```
bool hasTouched = false;

void OnMouseDown()
{

    ShoppingManager.instance.Message.SetActive (false);

    foreach (var characters in ShoppingManager.instance.ShoppingList) {

        Color clr = characters.Character_Holder.GetComponent<Image> ().color;
        clr.a = 1;
        characters.Character_Holder.GetComponent<Image> ().color = clr;

        if (!hasTouched) //if we havent touched
        {
        Vector3 TempVector = characters.CharaacterObject.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().localScale*Time.deltaTime;
        TempVector.x = 1.0f;
        TempVector.y = 1.0f;
        characters.CharaacterObject.GetComponent<RectTransform> ().localScale = TempVector;
        hasTouched = true; //then we scale it, and we have touched it
        }

    }
```

Comment: i try this script but still scale problem occurred.

Comment: hi @Chetan what happens now?  does ONE object go wrong or MANY? or what?

Comment: @Chetan You could also try `void OnMouseUp()` instead. Perhaps `OnMouseDown` checks for a continuous press?

Comment: @Tom  I try also OnMouseDown and OnMouseEnter.